# The page is lagging because of Yup validation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yup, react-final-form, final-form

I'm trying to make a form with around 20 fields.

The libraries, platforms I'm using:

- Material UI
- Final Form
- React Final Form
- MUI-RFF
- Yup

So when I create the form, everything works fine. But after I create Yup.Object for schema, the whole form lags, I means when I type it takes around half second to show on the screen. And then when I remove the validate prop from the Form element, everything works fine (the same happens when I remove Yup.Object validation).

Can someone help with this?